# Joint distribution of density forecasts

Tags: normal-distribution, forecasting, density-function, joint-distribution

I have a panel data set and I have created a model and finally I have obtained some density forecasts.

That is, I run my model for the $y_{it}$ and i obtain predictions for $\hat{y_{i,t+1}}$ , $\hat{y_{i,t+2}}$ ,..., $\hat{y_{i,t+h}}$  etc.

The $\hat{y_{i,t+1}}$ , $\hat{y_{i,t+2}}$ etc, **all** of them follow a normal distribution, but with different mean and variance. so $\hat{y_{i,t+1}} \sim N(\mu_{1},\sigma_{1}^{2})$ , $\hat{y_{i,t+2}} \sim N(\mu_{2},\sigma_{2}^{2})$, ..., $\hat{y_{i,t+h}} \sim N(\mu_{h},\sigma_{h}^{2})$.

My question is, what is their joint distribution ? And how can I obtain it ?

Edit: The $y_{it}$'s are the daily consumption of a product of individual $i$ at time $t$, so yes, they are highly correlated.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Your joint distribution may be [multivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution). Or it [may not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Joint_normality).

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thank you for your answer. How can I prove it ? Or how can I find their joint density ? I believe that most likely it will be a mixture of normals, but how could I prove it/write it formally ?

Comment: It will all depend very much on your model, in particular what kind of correlation structure will be forecasted. The next two realizations may each be separately simply normal, but highly positively or negatively correlated. I'm afraid we here won't be able to help you much. Examine your model.

Comment: Each one separately is indeed normal, but with different mean and variance. The $y_{it}$'s are the daily consumption of a product of individual $i$ at time $t$, so yes, they are highly correlated.

Comment: So, given that they are highly correlated, do you know if there is a way to find their joint distribution ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I suspect that "highly correlated" is not enough to pin down the joint distribution in any case. Plus, your model should come with specific assumptions about what output it will produce, so I'd suggest asking your model (or its author).